# Query to get all employees which are not assigned to a particular job

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

This query needs to select the employees whose first name or last contain the $term string, but then also check if those employees are already assigned to the job and return only those which are not assigned to the job. I am using an employee_job pivot table. As is, the query returns even those employees which are already assigned to the jobid and have a record in the pivot table.

```
 $employees = 
    Employee::where(function($query) use ($term) {
                    $query->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                          ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%'); })
              ->whereHas('jobs', function($query) use ($jobid) { $query->where('jobs.id','!=',$jobid); })
              ->take(5)->get();
```

I can tell the error is because it doesn't check if the count for the jobs with the jobid is 0, rather returns any employees which have any other jobs where the jobid doesn't match, even if they have a job that matches jobid.

I need something like this

```
$query->where('jobs.id',$jobid)->count() == 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `whereDoesntHave()`, instead of `whereHas()`:

```
$employees = Employee::where(function($query) use ($term) {
        $query->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
            ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('jobs', function($query) use ($jobid) {
        $query->where('jobs.id', $jobid);
    })
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

This will return the employees that don't have a job matching the given job id.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't in the database: query builder guide :( Probably should have looked at the API docs

Comment: @LaserBeak Yeah. There are a ton of functions available that aren't in the general documentation. Glad it helped.